# CSS. Can you nest @import files in css

Tags: css

Wondering if it is possible to nest @import calls in css.

Fo instance, if I am loading a stylesheet called style.css, and it imports a stylesheet called importedlevel1.css, which itself imports a stylesheet called importedlevel2.css, will all of the css be properly imported?

Comment: @MarcB True, but it'd take longer more than a minute to test browser and OS combinations exhibiting limitations.  Not everyone is a BrowserStack ninja.

Comment: Not to mention it can potentially help future users who have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but *beware Internet Explorer*: IE 8, 9, and I think 10 limits to [three levels deep](http://jorgealbaladejo.com/2011/05/28/internet-explorer-limits-nested-import-css-statements/).  This was a real pain fixing for Dojo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and the styles will apply properly but that's a lot of HTTP requests.